# How to reference enum types in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, enums, typing

I'm trying to create `Question` class that wants different types of answers/responses to a given situation. It might be a `DoAnswer` (e.g. "run") or a `CheckAnswer` (e.g. "check the clock"). I created different enums for those because there are only few possible actions and checks in my case and they all only need a reference-able name and a display string, which enum is perfect for. Now I want to somehow store the type of answer the question expects.

I thought of something like `answerType: enum;` but that doesn't work as you can't have enum as a value type. Java would have something like `Class<?> answerType` but I can't find a way to do something like this in TS.

The reason I need it is; I want to calculate the correct answer of a given type for a question by doing something like:

```
this.correctAnswers: DoAnswer[] | CheckAnswer[];

if(answerType is DoAnswer) {
  this.correctAnswers = answerService.calculateCorrectDoAnswers();
  // answerService gets my possibleAnswers and situationInQuestion
}
```

Maybe I'm just using every concept wrong but I don't see how I could make it better right now.

Comment: What are the definitions of `DoAnswer` and `CheckAnswer`?

Comment: DoAnswer and CheckAnswer are basically possible responses to a DoQuestion and CheckQuestion, see my comment to the answer of Andres below. Though there is only one DoQuestion and only one CheckQuestion but around 10 possible answers depending on a situation described in a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Enum**

```js
export enum Question {
  DoAnswer = 'run',
  CheckAnswer = 'check the clock'
};
```

**Type**

```js
export type QuestionType = Question.DoAnswer | Question.CheckAnswer;
```

**Component**

```js
check(answer: QuestionType): void {
    if (answer === 'run') {
      console.log('run')
    }

    if (answer === 'check the clock') {
      console.log('clock')
    }

    if (answer === 'something else') // ... doesn't compile since you don't have that value defined
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

Probably there is a better way, but you could do it like this:

**Types**

```js
export type DoAnswers =
  | 'run'
  | 'call the police'
  | 'call 911'
  | 'scream for help';

export type CheckAnswers =
  | 'check clock'
  | 'check weapon'
  | 'check location'
  | 'check cars';
```

**Answer utils**

```js
export const answersDo = ['run', 'call the police', 'call 911', 'scream for help'];
export const answersCheck = [
  'check clock',
  'check weapon',
  'check location',
  'check cars',
];
```

**Component**

```js
check(val: DoAnswers | CheckAnswers) {
    if (answersDo.includes(val)) {
      // its a do answer
    }

    if (answersCheck.includes(val)) {
      // its a check answer
    }
  }
```

Comment: This would only work if there is only one do/check answer. But I have around 10 of both and they are different in their type. E.g. if you're followed by someone you might either DO = run or call police or CHECK = if they have a weapon etc. But all answers are always either do or check because the question will be either "what do you do" or "what do you check for?"

Comment: This is a very interesting approach, thank you! :D

Comment: What if both DoAnswers and CheckAnswers have 'run' ?